# What are the most likely civilian applications for "powered armor"? On- and off-Earth?

Tags: armors

I am envisioning something developed as the next step beyond today's most cutting-edge powered exoskeleton tech (think of the Sarcos Guardian XO, but about 15-20 additional years worth of improvements). What industrial/commercial or scientific (*civilian*) applications can you think of that would require this kind of suit? Feel free to range a bit in your speculations but do keep any military stuff out, I'm not focused on making *District 9* or *Iron Man*-esque war suits.

Comment: I had to Google the Sarcos Guardian XO but I'm surprised I've never heard of it before, it looks cool as hell.

Comment: It would revolutionize valet parking....

Comment: This is an open ended question with no associated metric for evaluating the potential endless list requested as answer. Not the kind of questions we answer here.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest issue with powered exoskeleton tech I can think of, is that most issues they could solve, have already been solved another way. Mostly by unmanned robots.

Carrying stuff around, other than loading/offloading is more efficient with a vehicle. But even loading/offloading wouldn't be that efficient, as you don't have much extended range beyond the human body.

Holding large heavy items can be done, but transporting them, again, is better done by a conveyor belt of sorts. This allows speed and manufacturing precision rather than "just keep it steady"

The only valid applications I can see is in areas where automation is no option, due to having low accessibility (remote locations, mines, etc.). But a lot of these things could also be solved with unmanned robots, rather than human operated exoskeletons.

Even with a lot of future development, they would be fairly limiting, large and unwieldy, and restricting to flexibility. Often compact and more specialised or larger more powerful machines would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

"Armor" capability aside, a powered exoskeleton has long been looked forward to as an alternative to forklifts for loading heavy cargo -- the ability to lift a hundred kilos or more without strain or injury, and do it without the need to palletize or in a space too confined to maneuver a lift truck would be a major advantage -- even for a system much smaller than the power loader in *Aliens*.  It could also significantly speed up field repairs, by avoiding the need for jacks and hoists for things like tire changes, axle and brake repairs.

Hard rock and coal mining would be another likely application.  A powered suit would be much more maneuverable, hence could be used in tighter spaces than current mining machines (which are built low, but tend to be wide and long) -- and as a bonus could protect the wearer from rock falls and bad air (by having a built-in respirator system).

Comment: It's difficult to see how a man-shaped apparatus is the best choice here. Going to want things like bulldozer treads and large hydraulic powered scoops and jackhammers and such.  For example, changing a tire is accomplished pretty easily with a simpler bit of equipment. If you have ever seen a tow-truck operator change a flat at the side of the road, he uses the winch and a block of wood. When all you have is a hammer...

Comment: There is also the cost advantage of having a single versatile machine for a multitude of jobs.  Not as cost effective as a simple winch or jack, but your jack can't pick up a 200 kg crate and put it on a shoulder-high truck bed, and your winch can't push a bent fender off the wheel so you can drive out of the wilderness.  The powered suit can do both, if it's built right.